# How are radio waves different from the rest of the EMR spectrum?

Tags: visible-light, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, frequency, radio

Radio waves are generated by connecting high frequency AC electricity to an antenna (e.g. a dipole antenna), and we can control the frequency by the frequency of the AC. The frequency of other EMR (e.g. visible light) is dependent upon the frequency emitted by excited atoms over which we have no control. Also we can encode data into radio waves by frequency and amplitude modulation but not so for other forms of EMR (possible exception of pulsed lasers). Also radio waves penetrate our atmosphere whereas other forms don't or cannot.

So what is different in the nature of radio waves and why do we consider the EMR spactrum to be a continuum encompassing radio waves? (a double-bunger question)

Comment: Your premise isnt really correct as lasers can be made to emit many frequencies both visible and non visible, and can transmit information just like radio waves.

Comment: I am not sure of what my premise is that you think is incorrect. Lasers are selected wavelengths from the visible and near-visible frequency ranges that are concentrated into coherent monochrome beams: these can be phase/amplitude encoded, but no commercial applications exist yet for laser data transfer. They are generated by completely different processes, and laser beams are considered to consist of photons but radio waves are not. Lasers are collimated beams and radio waves are wave-like. The frequency/energy spectrum (see Anna V's chart) simply masks significant differences.

Comment: For one, fiber optic cable transmits data via visible light. Another thing is that cellular data is transmitted in the microwave bands. Both of these are counterexamples to your premise. Considering that the compact disk was a form of freezing in laser data to a solid surface to be read by another laser, it seems that lasers themselves indeed are used commercially to transfer data.

Comment: Re, "no commercial applications exist yet for laser data transfer," You might be surprised to learn how the backbone links of the internet work.

Answer (score 2):

This is the accepted [electromagnetic spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation#Electromagnetic_spectrum):

[image: spetem] [image]

Radio waves are identified as the low frequency part of the spectrum, frequency is the only difference.

*It is the interaction with matter that makes the difference*, as matter  responds  to different frequencies, that is what  makes the  radio waves behavior separate from the rest of the spectrum.

All matter is composed by atoms and molecules which are composed by charged particles. The spill over fields in neutral matter, and the ionization levels that can exist make the interaction of low frequency electromagnetic radiation different than the high frequency.

High frequency means small wavelength and the photons, which compose by superposition all electromagnetic fields, find most space empty, and do not interact enough to generate a difference in the wavefronts, matter is transparent for the wave fronts and thus higher frequencies cannot be used to transfer signals, the way radio frequencies can do.

Comment: You say that 'frequency is the only difference' and yet acknowledge photons in light and above frequencies. Isn't this a significant difference? Also light can travel as beams (of photons), occasionally forming waves (e.g. 2-slit experiments), whereas radio waves always radiate as waves. Both are EM radiation associated with specific frequencies, but seem to have quite different form and characteristics (e.g. light is not deflected by magnetic fields but radio waves are) that to me seems significant but are rarely mentioned or explained except in terms of generalities.

Comment: @Excentrix There are photons of *all* frequencies, including radio frequencies. *All* EM radiation of *all* frequencies can have *both* wave-like and particle-like behavior. Radio waves are *not* deflected by magnetic fields. The *only* difference between light and radio waves is frequency and wavelength (or energy and momentum). You have a *serious* misunderstanding of electromagnetic radiation.

Comment: I would concede that radio waves radiate as a wave-front and are not deflected by magnetic fields, but they are interfered with and distorted by magnetic fields: and particularly so in my poor TV reception area. And certainly I would be interested in any references that discuss radio waves in terms of consisting of photons and having particle-like characteristics. It would be greatly appreciated if you could provide some links to such material.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_line

Comment: Your poor TV reception is not related to magnetic fields interfering with or distorting electromagnetic waves. Electromagnetic fields simply superpose and have no effect on each other.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background Note the 33 occurrences of the word “photon” in this article about this cosmic radiation detected by *radio* telescopes. The CMB is treated theoretically as a [photon gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_gas) of radio-frequency photons. There are about 400 such CMB photons in each cubic centimeter of space.

Comment: All interference with EM wave propagation is due to interaction with charged particles of matter, not with other EM fields. What you see or hear as “interference” is typically just extra EM waves from unwanted sources.

Comment: @Excentrix  what G.Smith says . All frequency electromagnetic waves are a superposition of photons.wth energy h*nu, where nu is the frequency of the emergent light and h the planck constant

Comment: I want to thank Anna and G Smith for their great responses. I agree with superposition concept and that my TV interference is due to interference from matter: either reflection or or unwanted transmissions. The Wikipedia references provided by G Smith relate to microwave frequency emissions mainly from Hydrogen fine line emission spectrum (i.e. atom sources) and involve photons. Micro/radio waves artificially created from AC could represent a different non-photonic form of EMR to 'natural' atom-emission EMR, with there being an overlap of the 2 forms in the micro frequency band.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you see radio waves and visiblel light as two different phenomena, because they are genererated and described in different ways. However, both are in fact the same phenomenon and, as anna v already pointed out, only differ by their frequency.

When talking about visible light, you seem think the emission of a photon in an atom or a molecule. Regarding the often taught case of the Hydrogen spectral series, an electron loses some of it's energy. This exact amount of energy is emitted in form of a photon, which can then be detected as "visible light" e.g. by our eye.

As you already described, radio waves are generated in a seemingly different process: In an antenna, alternating current induces electromagnetic waves, which can be described by Maxwell's equations and the theory of Electromagnetism. These do not involve particles or quanta like photons.

However these two processes are essentially the same. We can understand this by considering the microscopic description of electrical current: displacement / movement of electrons in a conductor (now remember that I already talked about electrons when considering the emission of visible light). In an alternating current, these electrons are constantly accelerated and decelerated. Deceleration in particular means loss of kinetic energy. Similarly to the case above, the difference in energy is emitted in the form of photons. This process is called [Bremsstrahlung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung) (deceleration radiation).

Generally speaking, there are a lot of processes in which photons can be emitted, some can only create photons of a specific frequency, some not. Thus, physics treats all electromagnetic radiation as a single phenomenon, occuring at different frequencies, which can be classified on the electromagnetic spectrum.

If you want to know why electromagnetic radiation (including visible light) is sometimes described as a wave and sometimes as particles (photons) and why these descriptions are often interchangable, you can should read about the [Photoelectric effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelectric_effect) and [Double-slit experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment) (espacially with light, e.g. laser beams).

Comment: I agree that photons in the gamma to micro frequency range can be generated from a range of ways: from atoms, electrons and positrons, Bremsstrahlung, surface plasmons, electron/positron annihilation and a few others I am sure. But I believe that man-made micro/radio waves are formed from the electric fields generated around the antenna. This EM energy is cut off and pushed away from the antenna by the sudden AC generated change of polarity. Both forms are EM energy, but photonic is particle-like and man-made is wave-like without particle-like characteristics. That was the point of my post.

Comment: 1. Physics makes no difference if phenomena are "man-made" or not. I already explained how the induction of EM-waves by "man-made" AC relate to the emission of visible light (also EM-waves) by atomic processes.

Comment: 2) EM-waves and photons are two sides of the same coin. **This also applies, without a doubt, to your antenna**. Again, if you want to understand this, read about the photoelectric effect, double slit experiments with laser beams and the wave-particle duality (probability waves). 3) "But I believe..." So what exactly is your question? You got the same answer by three different people. How is one supposed to argue against your belief? One more time: "So what is different in the nature of radio waves?" -> There is none, they are the same phenomenon and differ only by their oscillation frequency.

Comment: 'Physics makes no difference if phenomena are "man-made" or not.'

Comment: 'Physics makes no difference if phenomena are "man-made" or not.' The differences are that we control the frequency via AC frequency and the resultant EMR is not photonic in nature. To me this is a reasonably significant couple of differences, just as there is a difference between incoherent and polarised light and optic vortex light: all are these 3 are EMR in the visible light range but each represents a  different form and characteristics. How big does a difference need to be to make it significant? Being different does not mean that there are not similarities in common.